# Find array, unexpected 0 !== 0

Tags: javascript

Can't get why this works this way?
To which type js converts item with value = 0 and why ?

```
if([1,2,0,1].find(item => item === 0)) {
    console.log(1); // logs nothing
}

console.log(0 === 0); // logs true
```

Comment: `find` returns the element it found, and `if(0)` never runs. You are looking for `.some(item => item === 0)` or `.includes(0)`, or `.find(item => item === 0) !== undefined`

Comment: `Array.prototype.find` returns the found item, which is `0` in this case, but `0` is a *falsy* value in JS, so that `if (0) console.log(1);` never happens.

Comment: Of course! Thank you, post it as an answer pls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns the element it found, and `0` is falsy so `if(0)` never runs the conditional block.

You should use `if (arr.includes(0))`. Alternatives that would also work, but are more ugly, are

- `if (arr.some(item => item === 0))`
- `if (arr.findIndex(item => item === 0) > -1)`
- `if (arr.find(item => item === 0) !== undefined)`

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't logs because the result of code below returns `0` which is a falsy value.

```
 const a = [1,2,0,1].find(item => item === 0)
 console.log(a)  //a is 0
```

So the statement inside if block doesn't get executed.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `[1,2,0,1].find(item => item === 0)` in the console, you'll see the output is `0`. So it does find your element and returns it.

Then, why is there no `1` printed from `console.log`? That's because `0` is falsy, and you are now doing `if (0)`, so your condition is never true.

There are multiple solutions to this, depending on the use case some make more sense than others:

**1) Check explicitly for `!== undefined`**

```js
if ([1,2,0,1].find(item => item === 0) !== undefined) { /* ... */ }
```

If `find` doesn't find anything matching your criteria, it returns `undefined`, so checking if the return value *isn't* `undefined` you'll know the element was found.

Downside: If `undefined` is a possible value that may actually be searched for, this yet again fails.

Also, this would only make sense if in your real code you'd store the found element in a variable to not only check for its existence but also use it for something else later, otherwise one of the other two options below would be a better choice.

**2) Use `some` instead of `find`**

Since you are just interested in whether *something* was found, and not which element exactly, you could just use `some` which returns `true`/`false` instead of `find` which returns the found element itself.

```js
if ([1,2,0,1].some(item => item === 0)) { /* ... */ }
```

**3) Use `includes` to directly look for the element by value**

Since you seem to just have an `item === someValue` check, you don't really need to use one of the methods that take a callback in the first place, since you could specify the element by value and use `includes`, which returns `true`/`false`:

```js
if ([1,2,0,1].includes(0)) { /* ... */ }
```